# Structure/Reading of IE cache index.dat

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, caching, structure

Is there any example on reading IE cache file (index.dat and friends found in Temporary Internet Files folder)? I'm fine with example in almost any (sane) programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Use [FindFirst](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384026(VS.85).aspx)/[FindNextUrlCacheEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384049(v=VS.85).aspx).  It's pretty straightforward.  The struct you pass to it contains all the info from the file.